# getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException : Index 3 requested, with a size of 3

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am new to android ,i am learning sqlitedatabase

code:

```
package com.example.sqlitetest;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.strictmode.SqliteObjectLeakedViolation;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase database;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        database = openOrCreateDatabase("Users",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(name VARCHAR,age INT(3),id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age) VALUES ('NICK',27)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age) VALUES ('sean',23)");
        database.execSQL("INSERT INTO users(name,age) VALUES ('john',15)");

        Cursor c= database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users ",null);
        int nameindex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int idindex=c.getColumnIndex("id");
        c.moveToFirst();
        while(c!=null && c.getCount()>0){
                Log.i("name",c.getString(nameindex));
                Log.i("id",c.getString(idindex));
                c.moveToNext();
        }
    }
}
```

log cat

```
2019-12-23 18:11:05.437 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest I/name: NICK
2019-12-23 18:11:05.437 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest I/id: 1
2019-12-23 18:11:05.437 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest I/name: sean
2019-12-23 18:11:05.437 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest I/id: 2
2019-12-23 18:11:05.437 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest I/name: john
2019-12-23 18:11:05.437 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest I/id: 3
2019-12-23 18:11:05.438 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-12-23 18:11:05.440 12802-12802/com.example.sqlitetest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sqlitetest, PID: 12802
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sqlitetest/com.example.sqlitetest.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 requested, with a size of 3
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 requested, with a size of 3
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:515)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:138)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:52)
        at com.example.sqlitetest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791
```

output is getting printed but when while loop ends i am getting exception

i am using cursor and setting a while loop while (c!=null)
but i am getting CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

i tried using

```
while(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
```

but this gets stuck on 1st name

Thanks for help!

Comment: `while(c!=null && c.getCount()>0)` think about how long this will iterate

Comment: I recommend you tu learn Room instead of using SQLite because of that it more reliable

Comment: i will learn that but before that can u help with my this doubt @AsadMukhtar

Comment: @juergend tried your answer but that way its skipping 1st index element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do this following**

```
if (c!= null && c.getCount() > 0) 
{
       c.moveToFirst();
       do {
            int nameindex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
            int idindex=c.getColumnIndex("id");
         }
        while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks , exception is gone but can u explain what u did bcz initially my c is not null and c.getCount()=3 and when my while loop runs it stops when c is null but why does that cause exception to occur? @rakesh

Comment: @Tarandeepsingh, If there is no record or structure column name different than actual, then It may return null. If it solved your issue then upvote it and a mark is a correct answer